# How to generate a random String in Java

Tags: java, string, random, char

I have an object called `Student`, and it has `studentName`, `studentId`, `studentAddress`, etc. For the `studentId`, I have to generate random string consist of seven numeric charaters,
eg.

```
studentId = getRandomId();
studentId = "1234567" <-- from the random generator.
```

And I have to make sure that there is no duplicate id.

Comment: If I read your question correctly, you want to generate a random number R such that 1,000,000 <= R <= 9,999,999, and then turn that into a string?

Comment: would that be easier to generate a random number first then convert it to a string?

Comment: So, how did the homework assignment go?

Comment: These 3 single line codes are very much useful i guess..
`Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));`
`UUID.randomUUID().toString();`
`RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(16);`

Comment: how can you ensure uniqueness given limited dimension of data? If number of students exceeds 10^7, you'll have no way to assign a unique number to each.

Answer (score 132):

Generating a random string of characters is easy - just use `java.util.Random` and a string containing all the characters you want to be available, e.g.

```
public static String generateString(Random rng, String characters, int length)
{
    char[] text = new char[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        text[i] = characters.charAt(rng.nextInt(characters.length()));
    }
    return new String(text);
}
```

Now, for uniqueness you'll need to store the generated strings somewhere. How you do that will really depend on the rest of your application.

Comment: the method require String characters, how do i specify this characters?
String characters = "123456789"; ???

Comment: @chandra: Yes, exactly. Give it a string of the characters you want to select from. So if you only wanted digits you'd pass in "0123456789". If you wanted only capital letters you'd pass in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" etc.

Comment: Is this more correct that using `UUID.randomUUID().toString()`? If so, why?

Comment: @Is7aq: Well it provides considerably more control over the output, both in terms of which characters are used and how long the string is.

Comment: Why did you pass Random as a parameter ?

Comment: @RockOnGom First I too thought the same but then I realized mostly I will be using this method in generating random string to be added in a list, probably in a for loop. So by passing random I can avoid initialization in each call

Comment: @RockOnGom: Sorry, I'd missed this comment before. For things like this, I view the `Random` as effectively a dependency - accepting it here allows the caller to decide whether to use a preseeded `Random` to get repeatable results (e.g. for tests), a `SecureRandom` to make it suitable for security purposes, etc.

Comment: always same output

Comment: @rohitmandiwal: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment... if you were asking for an explanation of some behaviour, you need to provide a *lot* more information.

Answer (score 57):

This is very nice:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html

...something like `RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(7)`.

There are 10^7 equiprobable (if `java.util.Random` is not broken) distinct values so uniqueness may be a concern.

Comment: [http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) is broken!!!

Comment: security hash is not for uniqueness, it is for hiding initial value

Answer (score 18):

You can also use UUID class from java.util package, which returns random uuid of 32bit characters String.

`java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()`

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

Comment: That's not the same as "a random string of 7 numeric characters" though.

Comment: Random UUIDs are basically guaranteed to be unique though.  If you need numeric string from that then hash it.

Answer (score 5):

```
Random ran = new Random();
int top = 3;
char data = ' ';
String dat = "";

for (int i=0; i<=top; i++) {
  data = (char)(ran.nextInt(25)+97);
  dat = data + dat;
}

System.out.println(dat);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the following class code will help you. It supports multithreading but you can do some improvement like remove sync block and and sync to getRandomId() method.

```
public class RandomNumberGenerator {

private static final Set<String> generatedNumbers = new HashSet<String>();

public RandomNumberGenerator() {
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int maxLength = 7;
    final int maxTry = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ". studentId=" + RandomNumberGenerator.getRandomId(maxLength, maxTry));
    }
}

public static String getRandomId(final int maxLength, final int maxTry) {
    final Random random = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    final int max = (int) Math.pow(10, maxLength);
    final int maxMin = (int) Math.pow(10, maxLength-1);
    int i = 0;
    boolean unique = false;
    int randomId = -1;
    while (i < maxTry) {
        randomId = random.nextInt(max - maxMin - 1) + maxMin;

        synchronized (generatedNumbers) {
            if (generatedNumbers.contains(randomId) == false) {
                unique = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (unique == false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot generate unique id!");
    }

    synchronized (generatedNumbers) {
        generatedNumbers.add(String.valueOf(randomId));
    }

    return String.valueOf(randomId);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first question you need to ask is whether you really need the ID to be random. Sometime, sequential IDs are good enough.

Now, if you do need it to be random, we first note a generated sequence of numbers that contain no duplicates can not be called random. :p Now that we get that out of the way, the fastest way to do this is to have a `Hashtable` or `HashMap` containing all the IDs already generated. Whenever a new ID is generated, check it against the hashtable, re-generate if the ID already occurs. This will generally work well if the number of students is much less than the range of the IDs. If not, you're in deeper trouble as the probability of needing to regenerate an ID increases, P(generate new ID) = number_of_id_already_generated / number_of_all_possible_ids. In this case, check back the first paragraph (do you need the ID to be random?).

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes it has to be random, that is what my project specification said

Answer (score 1):

Many possibilities...

You know how to generate randomly an integer right?
You can thus generate a char from it... (ex 65 -> A)

It depends what you need, the level of randomness, the security involved... but for a school project i guess getting UUID substring would fit :)

Comment: ya its just for a school project so i dont need to concern about security and stuff, but UUID produce 32char String, all i need is 7..
ow i just got an idea, is it possible to take only the 7 first char from 32?

Comment: Using substring... what i said :)